# How to show a button expand/collapse with animation in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to add a button in **absolute** position in react-native. I have tried with FAB button but it is not full-filling my requirement.Attached the screen for the reference. I am new to react-native. Please help.[image: anim1[![anim2]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oWvG.png)

Answer (score 0):

React native has good solution for your case. [See](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layoutanimation) `LayoutAnimations` library of `react-native` in code this would be like this:

```
/* your code*/
{buttonsVisible&&<Button onClick={()=>{
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.Linear)
    setButtonVisible(!buttonVisible)
}}/>}
/* your code*/
```

PS. Note that in order to get this to work on **Android** you need to set the following flags via `UIManager`:

```
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  if (UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental) {
    UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
  }
}
```